# Suggestion on how to drive a robot to an Aruco marker

Tags: ros-kinetic, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I intend to build a base to recharge the batteries of a differential robot that implements ROS for autonomous navigation. Currently, my robot has a PI Camera and can locate an Aruco marker by turning on itself. With a raspberry pi 4, I get a rate of 60 fps with a resolution of 640x480.
My question is, what is the best way to make the robot approach the recharge base, observing an Aruco marker:

- Maybe using a PID controller
- Estimate the distance and orientation that the robot is in relation to the marker and publish goals in the odometry frame and let the ROS guide the robot to the goal
- other way..

Has anyone implemented something similar and could give me a suggestion?

[image: image description]

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344861/suggestion-on-how-to-drive-a-robot-to-an-aruco-marker./) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2020-02-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pran-Seven](https://answers.ros.org/users/114194/pran-seven/) on 2023-02-14**:
Hey, were you able to find an implementation for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [demo_pioneer](http://wiki.ros.org/demo_pioneer) , works fairly okay.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2020-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0